# Printing every item on a new line in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, lambda, list-comprehension

my function looks like this:

```
def factorial(x):
        result = 1
        for item in range(1,x+1):
            result *= item
        return result 

print [factorial(x) for x in range(0,6)]
```

I'd like to print every result on a new line - could somebody please show me how to do this, perhaps using list comprehension or a lambda function of some kind - I'm trying to get the hang of them, so it'd be just awesome ;)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should be just:

```
print '\n'.join([str(factorial(x)) for x in range(0, 6)])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's just what I've been looking for :)